# React Native: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

my react native application throws this error when i navigate to a specific component. I am using functional component.

This is my useEffect method.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (mounted) {
      getSingleProject(route.params.itemId);
      console.log(singleProject && singleProject);
    }
    return () => {
      mounted = false;
      console.log("cleanup");
    };
  }, [getSingleProject, route.params.itemId])
```

I have tried another solution from other answers but i doesn't help

This is my action method

```
export const getSingleProject = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("This method us called");

  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
  };
  await axios
    .get(`${API_URL}/project/single/${id}`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data, "this is from actions");

      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT_ERROR,
        payload: err,
      });
    });
}
```

**This is my reducer.**

```
export default function (state = initiastate, actions) {
  const { type, payload } = actions;

    case GET_SINGLE_PROJECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        singleProject: payload,
        loading: false,
      };
```

Thank you.

Comment: To remove - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component warning, use componentDidMount method under a condition and make false that condition on componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: I have done that in the useeffect method.

Comment: No, in two different methods.

Comment: Is there any way to do that in functional component ?

Comment: Use ``componentDidMount`` and ``componentWillUnmonut``. On the former, make the condition true and on the latter make the condition false.

Comment: Since, I am using functional component so and this lifecycle methods can only be used in a class base component i guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214061/discussion-between-zixuan-and-vishal-acharya).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to prevent all the state updates if the component has been unmounted (in your case it would be `dispatch` calls). By assigning `mounted = false;` you're not achieving anything since your request is already ongoing. Instead of assigning false, in the cleanup function you need to cancel that request to prevent execution of its success/error callbacks where `dispatch` is called.

I'm not very familiar with `axios`, but according to its docs you can create a cancellation token and pass it to your `axios` call, so the whole solution would be something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();
    getSingleProject(route.params.itemId, source);

    return () => {
      source.cancel();
      console.log("cleanup");
    };
  }, [getSingleProject, route.params.itemId])
```

```
export const getSingleProject = (id, source) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("This method us called");

  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: await AsyncStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
    cancelToken: source.token
  };
  await axios
    .get(`${API_URL}/project/single/${id}`, config)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data, "this is from actions");

      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_PROJECT_ERROR,
        payload: err,
      });
    });
}
```